# Getting warning CS0469 how to solve?

Tags: c#, error-handling

I'm relatively new to coding, and decided to make a fps game. So far, I've followed a tutorial on how to look around and I have this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
    public float xRotation = 0f;
    Transform playerBody;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        xRotation -= mouseY;
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

Whenever I try to run this, I get warning CS0649. Why?

Comment: But if i do run it, at least I can look up and down, but not left and right.

Comment: Compiler Warning CS0649 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0649

Comment: This warning means you didn't initialize your field any data, so it will always have a default value.